# Go - What is really a multipart.File?

Tags: go

In [the docs](http://golang.org/pkg/mime/multipart/#File) it is said that

> If stored on disk, the File's underlying concrete type will be an
>   *os.File.

In this case everything is clear. Great. But, what happens if not, if the file is stored in memory?

My actual problem is that I´m trying to get the size of the different files stored in memory that I got though an html form but I can not use os.Stat to do fileInfo.Size() because I don´t have the location of the file, just it´s name.

```
fhs := req.MultipartForm.File["files"]
for _, fileHeader := range fhs {
    file, _ := fileHeader.Open()
    log.Println(len(file)) // Gives an error because is of type multipart.File
    fileInfo, err  := os.Stat(fileHeader.Filename) // Gives an error because it´s just the name, not the complete path

    // Here I would do things with the file
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can exploit the fact that multipart.File implements io.Seeker to find its size.

```
cur, err := file.Seek(0, 1)
size, err := file.Seek(0, 2)
_, err := file.Seek(cur, 0)
```

The first line finds the file's current offset. The second seeks to the end of the file and returns where it is in relation to the beginning of the file. This is the size of the file. The third seeks to the offset we were at before trying to find the size.

You can read more about the seek method [here](http://golang.org/pkg/io/#Seeker).

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking in a possible solution like this one but never used the Seek method and did not know that it was so easy to use :)

Answer (score 2):

if you call `parseMultipartForm(0)` this will write the entire file to disk instead of storing anything in memory, followed by `f, _ := FormFile("file")` then you can stat the file with `fi, _ := f.(*os.File).Stat()`

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you want to do with the data, the best thing to do may be to read the file into a byte slice with ioutil.ReadAll. (You might want the data as a byte slice eventually, anyway.) Once you've done that, you an find the length with len.